# Add multiple products to cart in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I add new module in magento 1.7.0.2.I have done according to the article. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9797/P30/.
When I added three products at the same time,but only one product can show correct price,others is $0.00 and Subiotal is wrong in it.Then I click on top of "My Cart" page,The price of correct in "My Cart" on the sidebar.

app/code/local/Perpetual/MultiAdd/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php

```
require_once('Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php');
class Perpetual_MultiAdd_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
     /**
     * Adding multiple products to shopping cart action
     * based on Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()
     * see also http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8610/
     * and http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_overload_a_controller
     */
    public function addmultipleAction()
    {
        $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('products');
        if (!is_array($productIds)) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }
        foreach( $productIds as $productId) {
            try {
                $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty' . $productId, 0);
                if ($qty <= 0) continue; // nothing to add
                $cart = $this->_getCart();
                $cart->init();
                //$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->init();
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->load($productId)
                    ->setConfiguredAttributes($this->getRequest()->getParam('super_attribute'))
                    ->setGroupedProducts($this->getRequest()->getParam('super_group', array()));
                $eventArgs = array(
                    'product' => $product,
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                    'response' => $this->getResponse(),
                );
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_before_add', $eventArgs);

                $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_after_add', $eventArgs);
                $cart->save();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
                $message = $this->__('%s was successfully added to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());    
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
                else {
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, $this->__('Can not add item to shopping cart'));
            }
        }
        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

my template:

```
...
<form action="<?php echo $this->helper('multiadd/cart')->getAddToCartUrl() ?>" method="post" id="productAddToCartForm">
    ...
    <label for="qty<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" id="qty<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):0) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
    ...
    <button class="button btn-cart" type="button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
...
```

app\code\local\Perpetual\MultiAdd\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Perpetual_MultiAdd>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Perpetual_MultiAdd>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <perpetual_multiadd_checkout_cart>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/addmultiple/.*$#]]></from>
                <to>/multiadd/checkout_cart/addmultiple/</to>
            </perpetual_multiadd_checkout_cart> 
        </rewrite>
        <helpers>
            <multiadd>
                <class>Perpetual_MultiAdd_Helper</class>
            </multiadd>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <perpetual_multiadd>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Perpetual_MultiAdd</module>
                    <frontName>multiadd</frontName>
                </args>
            </perpetual_multiadd>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Perpetual\MultiAdd\Helper\Cart.php

```
<?php
class Perpetual_MultiAdd_Helper_Cart extends Mage_Core_Helper_Url
{
    /**
     * Return url to add multiple items to the cart
     * @return  url
     */
    public function getAddToCartUrl()
    {
        if ($currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
            $continueShoppingUrl = $currentCategory->getUrl();
        } else {
            $continueShoppingUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true));
        }

        $params = array(
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($continueShoppingUrl)
        );

        if ($this->_getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'checkout'
            && $this->_getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'cart') {
            $params['in_cart'] = 1;
        }
        return $this->_getUrl('checkout/cart/addmultiple', $params);
    }
}
?>
```

app\etc\modules\Perpetual_MultiAdd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Perpetual_MultiAdd>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Perpetual_MultiAdd>
    </modules>
</config>
```

How to fix the wrong price in "My Cart" on the sidebar?
I'm sorry for my English,it's not my home language.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `$cart = $this->_getCart();` and `$cart->save();` outside foreach.

```
require_once('Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php');
class Perpetual_MultiAdd_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
     /**
     * Adding multiple products to shopping cart action
     * based on Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()
     * see also http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8610/
     * and http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_overload_a_controller
     */
    public function addmultipleAction()
    {
        $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('products');
        if (!is_array($productIds)) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }


        $cart = $this->_getCart();

        foreach( $productIds as $productId) {

            try {
                $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty' . $productId, 0);
                if ($qty <= 0) continue; // nothing to add
                //$cart = $this->_getCart();
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->load($productId)
                    ->setConfiguredAttributes($this->getRequest()->getParam('super_attribute'))
                    ->setGroupedProducts($this->getRequest()->getParam('super_group', array()));
                $eventArgs = array(
                    'product' => $product,
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                    'response' => $this->getResponse(),
                );
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_before_add', $eventArgs);

                //$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->init();

                $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_after_add', $eventArgs);
                //$cart->save();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
                $message = $this->__('%s was successfully added to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());    
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
                else {
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, $this->__('Can not add item to shopping cart'));
            }

        }
        $cart->save();

        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to achieve the same in magento2?

Answer (score 2):

Found it! Put this anywhere after your cart save. It will reset your cart and reload your quote to recalculate the prices of all products.

```
Mage::unregister('_singleton/checkout/cart');
Mage::unregister('_singleton/checkout/session');
$cart = $this->_getCart();
$this->_getQuote();
if ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
    $cart->init();
    $cart->save();
}
```

Comment: This is still working and it was very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

May be this one will help:

http://deepakbhatta.com/magento-add-multiple-items-to-cart/

Overview is:

```
 $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
        $ms="";
        foreach($validProducts as $sku => $qty) {
            $params = array('qty' => $qty);
            $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);;
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $msg .= $product->getName(). " is successfully added into cart<br>";
        }
         $cart->save();
```

Answer (score -2):

Recently, we have launched a free top-notch extension - **Add Multiple Products** to Cart for Magento to improve the online shopping experience of customers.

This extension allows users to add multiple products and add all to the cart with a single click. More importantly, it will allow the customers to enter the Quantity from category page itself.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-multiple-products-to-cart.html

This is exactly what you need.